# Vectorized method to find matching values between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to locate the most recent rows within my Dataframe that contain the same values in two separate columns.

Presently, I am doing this slowly with looping, but I suspect there's a way to cleverly use the `apply` method or some other vectorized function to do this faster. 
My present code:

```
def enumerate_matching(df):
    a = list(df['A'])
    b = list(df['B'])
    matching = []

    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(b)):
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                matching.append(i)
                matching.append(i+j)
                break
    return matching
```

Is there a faster method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use set to get the intersection (it has a complexity logarithmic in the size of the sets a and b)

```
 a = set(df['A'])
 b = set(df['B'])
 a.intersection(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the matching line by line, you should do:

```
np.sum(df['A'] == df['B'])
```